# How to change the time zone on a query result

Tags: mysql, date, format, subquery

I have the following query that works as intended -

```
SELECT
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Order Number' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Order Number`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Date' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Date`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Creditor Name' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Creditor Name`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Purchaser' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Purchaser`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Farm' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Farm`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Quantity' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Quantity`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Description' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Description`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Allocation' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Allocation`
From `inspection_items`
where `template_id` = 'template_xxxx' and `type` not like 'section' and `type` not like 'information' and `type`not like 'element' and `type` not like 'dynamicfield'
group by `parent_id`, `audit_id`
order by `created_at`,`item_index`
```

However I also need to change the date which I can do by this query -

```
SELECT `response`, Date_format(Convert_TZ(STR_TO_DATE(`response`, '%Y-%c-%dT%H:%i:%s'), '+00:00', '+10:00'), '%Y-%c-%d %H:%i:%s') as 'Date'
from `inspection_items`
```

However how do I bring these 2 queries together to change the date in the first query result?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, you want to format `Date` field in your first query, the way you have formatted in your second query.

Try this -

```
SELECT
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Order Number' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Order Number`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Date' THEN Date_format(Convert_TZ(STR_TO_DATE(`response`, '%Y-%c-%dT%H:%i:%s') else '' END)as `Date`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Creditor Name' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Creditor Name`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Purchaser' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Purchaser`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Farm' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Farm`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Quantity' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Quantity`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Description' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Description`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Allocation' THEN `response` else '' END)as `Allocation`
From `inspection_items`
where `template_id` = 'template_xxxx' and `type` not like 'section' and `type` not like 'information' and `type`not like 'element' and `type` not like 'dynamicfield'
group by `parent_id`, `audit_id`
order by `created_at`,`item_index`
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However when I tried the new query I received a sql error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'else '' END)as `Date`,
max(CASE WHEN `label` = 'Creditor Name' THEN `response` ' at line 3

Comment: Apologies - fixed by including the whole second query for Date_format. It works perfectly so thankyou.